# ARKit - Weaknesses anchoring models on vertical plan

Tags: ios, arkit

For few months, I have tested ARKit on some demonstration projects, and I have noticed that the models anchoring on vertical plan can be very unstable. Sometimes, the 3D models can go up or down on the vertical plan. This can be critical for some cases. We know, the anchoring depends on a multitude of parameters and the environment.

I would like to have some of your feedbacks, experiences on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Plane detection and anchoring is dependent on the actual surface color and decoration, both vertical and horizontal are more stable and easily detected if there are some visual features instead of plain dry surfaces

TODO list: try to glue a vertical plane to an horizontal one